# Webp Images Taking much time to load

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has huge size of images, I wanted to reduce the size, I have achieved reducing the size by using webp format images. I followed [this](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/WebP-iOS-example).but the sad part is, It is taking so much of time to load images as a result my app performance is vey slow.Could any one help how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use fewer/smaller images?

Comment: my app reqiurement is to use many images each of 1.2 mb size which is minimum.there are too many such images.so am using webp.

Comment: my app has a requirement, which needs to display many images, so am using webp images to reduce the size .There is no chance to use fewer number of images.

Comment: But you probably don't need to display them all at once; can you defer loading the ones that don't need to be displayed immediately, so the user sees feedback sooner?